# Not sure what is wrong

Tags: python

Given caffeine amount (in mg) as input, output the caffeine level after 6, 12, and 18 hours. Use a string formatting expression with conversion specifiers to output the caffeine amount as floating-point numbers.

Output each floating-point value with two digits after the decimal point, which can be achieved as follows:
print('%0.2f' % your_value)

I have tried multiple variations on the code using a different number and I am not sure why it is not halfing. I am EXTREMELY new to Python

```
caffeine_mg = float(input())

print('After 6 hours:', '%0.2f' % caffeine_mg)
print('After 12 hours:', '%0.2f' % caffeine_mg)
print('After 18 hours:', '%0.2f' % caffeine_mg)
```

With 100 as the input The expected results should be:

```
After 6 hours: 50.00 mg
After 12 hours: 25.00 mg
After 18 hours: 12.50 mg
```

My results:

```
After 6 hours: 100.00
After 12 hours: 100.0000
After 18 hours: 100.000000
```

Comment: Firstly, those are not the results from this code. And why would you expect the output to change, when you never change the value of caffeine_mg?

Answer (score 1):

```
caffeine_mg = float(input())

mg1 = (caffeine_mg) / 2

mg2 = (caffeine_mg) / 4

mg3 = (caffeine_mg) / 16

print('After 6 hours: {:.2f} mg'.format(mg1))

print('After 12 hours: {:.2f} mg'.format(mg2))

print('After 24 hours: {:.2f} mg'.format(mg3))
```

Comment: Hi, can you please explain what's going on in the code? It might be correct or even be the best way to solve the problem, but it's important to explain the logic and process behind

Answer (score 0):

Because you aren't doing anything to halve the input.  You just keep printing `caffeine_mg` in each `print`.  To halve the value of `caffeine_mg`, you need to divide it by 2 or multiply it by 0.5.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I think you want to code:

```
def caffeine_calc(amount):
  x1 = 0.5*amount
  x2 = 0.5*x1
  x3 = 0.5*x2
  print('After 6 hours:' + str(x1) + ' mg')
  print('After 12 hours:' + str(x2) + 'mg')
  print('After 18 hours:' + str(x3) + 'mg')

caffeine_calc(float(input("Please enter the amount of caffeine you want to calculate: ")))
```

Firstly, I defined a function called 'caffeine_calc' which takes an input called 'amount'. It then calculates three different variables (x1, x2, x3) and then prints these, surrounded by certain strings.

After defining the function, one has to call it. This can be done by simply writing the name of the function. The input will be entered by the user and this input will be converted to be a float.

The output for an input of 100 is

```
After 6 hours:20.0 mg
After 12 hours:10.0mg
After 18 hours:5.0mg
```

Did this help you?

Comment: This was almost what I needed but the output is wrong, The output should be 50.00 25.00 and 12.50. It should be to two decimal places.

Comment: Actually, the output should be 50, 25 and 12.5, I must have typed in a wrong input. For the exact amount of decimals you might want to check out the decimals module and see if that gives you the function you need: https://docs.python.org/3/library/decimal.html